# Kubernetes: Could not find finalized endpoint being pointed to. Error validating service: Error getting service: services not found

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Any suggestions why I'm getting this error:

```
Error opening service: Could not find finalized endpoint being pointed to by wordpress: Error validating service: Error getting service wordpress: services "wordpress" not found
```

at the end of this tutorial: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/mysql-wordpress-persistent-volume/#deploy-wordpress

I can see the service - e.g.

```
kubectl get services
NAME              TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
wordpress         LoadBalancer   10.104.201.62   <pending>     80:32308/TCP   2m37s
wordpress-mysql   ClusterIP      None            <none>        3306/TCP       4m11s
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah - I needed to specify the namespace.